# Skipping Dispose on Deactivation in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-2

I am just starting to use Ninject on a (large) project and am wading in by only using DI for a portion of it to start. I have a subsystem that is organized using constructor injection extensively. Using Ninject to inject all of the dependencies between classes in this subystem is working great. However, I have dependencies on things outside of the subystem that I would really like to use Ninject to automatically inject as well, but not to be in charge of their lifecycle.

I thought `Bind<T>.ToConstant(...)` would work for what I am trying to do. For instance, I may have a class of type Monkey that is to act as a Singleton, but another part of my application is handling its lifecycle without Ninject (for example, creating it and disposing it manually). When my Ninject-equipped subsystem gets created I instantiate a kernel, bind my subsystem classes, and then use something like `Bind<Monkey>.ToConstant(Monkey.Instance)` to bind to various "external" dependencies. This works great at activation time but does not work as needed when I dispose the kernel. My subsystem can have a shorter lifecycle than these external dependencies, but when I call Dispose on the kernel all of these dependencies get disposed, which is not what I want. While I can see arguments both ways, it seems a bit questionable that Ninject would automatically dispose an object that it did not create. I'm hoping there is at least a way to opt out of this behavior, but so far I have not found anything. Is there any support for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `InTransientScope` to your constant object.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Just for my own understanding, I understand how Transient scope works for activation. For deactivation, is it true that Ninject will never Dispose the instances it creates when using Transient scope (I may have missed this point in my reading). Also, for constants, is the only difference between the default Singleton and Transient scope whether the object is disposed when deactivated?